# Creating hanging indents on paragraph's content without using negative text-indent

Tags: html, css

So I want to indent every line except the first, i.e. hanging indent which is mentioned in the specification of text-indent property, but is not supported by browsers. Only way I have found to make it work is setting margin-left (or padding-left) of `20px` on the entire block, and then giving it text-indent `-20px` that would affect only the first line of the block/paragraph.

```css
.hanging-indent {
  text-indent: -20px; /* Negative value to indent the first line to the left */
  padding-left: 20px; /* Positive value to offset subsequent lines */
}
```

```html
<div class="hanging-indent">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.</p>
  </div>
```

The problem is if I have a element with `float` property set before my paragraph, this negative `text-indent` makes my first word go above the `float` element.

```css
.hanging-indent {
  text-indent: -20px; /* Negative value to indent the first line to the left */
  margin-left: 20px; /* Positive value to offset subsequent lines */
  width: 700px;       /* Not important */
}

:root {
  --page-width: 700px;
  --page-height: 100px;
  --top-margin: 10px;
  --left-margin: 10px;
  --bottom-margin: 10px;
  --right-margin: 10px;
}
.soup-image {
  display: block;
  width: 700px;
  height: calc(var(--page-height) + 20px);
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% var(--top-margin), 0 var(--top-margin), 0 calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px), 100% calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px), 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(white var(--top-margin), transparent var(--top-margin), transparent calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px), white calc(100% - 1 * var(--bottom-margin) - 20px));
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="soup-image"></div>

<p class="hanging-indent">
    Lo ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eget lorem nunc. Nulla facilisi. Nam feugiat velit vel turpis malesuada, in sodales risus tristique. Vestibulum sagittis vehicula nunc, non hendrerit odio ultrices et. Fusce consectetur eget turpis eu lobortis.
</p>
```

How to make the first line stay in below the float element?

Thanks.

Comment: The inline content following the floated element floats around that element, but the paragraph itself goes over the full with, starting from the same top position as the floated element. And the negative text-indent then simply drags the first line "over" the image. Not sure if there is any other solution here, than to give the image itself a corresponding margin-right.

Comment: I am not sure how to solve it with margin-right, could you give it a try? Thanks.

Comment: Not really clear how you want it to look - do you still want to keep the text-indent and just move the whole text over a bit (margin-left on the floated element then), or do you just want to drop the text-indent then, so that all lines of text will start at the same position?

Comment: @CBroe If you write "Lorem" instead of "Lo" as the first word, that achieves the desired display.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell what it is actually supposed to behave like, based on that snippet where the floated element isn't even visible. Also can't tell what exactly the `shape-outside` does with the snippet either.